# what are the sizes of integer and array in python and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to determine the sizes of different data types in python, and wrote the following code. Each line's outputs are shown as comments beside them.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
print(sys.version) # 3.6.7
print(np.version.version) # 1.15.4

i = 2
print(type(i)) # <class 'int'>
print(sys.getsizeof(i)) # 28

j = np.int64(3)
print(type(j)) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
print(sys.getsizeof(j)) # 32

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(type(a)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(sys.getsizeof(a))   # 160
print(type(a[0][0])) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
print(sys.getsizeof(a[0][0])) # 32

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
print(sys.getsizeof(a))   # 176
```

From the above outputs, size of a 6 element array is 160 and size of a 8 element array is 176, so can I conclude that size of each element in the array is 8 bytes and the size of the array's header (constant) is 112 bytes? Is the size of each element constant or depends on its value (large or small)?

Also, when I am printing the size of a[0][0] why am I getting 32 and not 8? What exactly is the maths behind python and numpy integers and arrays?

Comment: `a[0][0]` is also a `numpy.ndarray`. Why not expect 120?

Comment: Numpy is coded in cython, so this is C underneath, I do not think you can really rely on the size of pyhon ints (I think they are translated to long in C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually "**sys.getsizeof**" is not a suitable function to determine the size in numpy. It just works out for built-in python objects.

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.
>
> getsizeof() calls the object’s **sizeof** method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

For *numpy.ndarray* use *nbytes* which is *size* * *itemsize*

```
a = np.array([[3,4],[8,0],[9,8],[7,0]])
a.size # 8
a.itemsize # 8
a.nbytes # 64
a = np.array([[3,4],[8,0],[9,8],[7,0]],dtype=np.int32)
a.size # 8
a.itemsize # 4
a.nbytes # 32
```